# How to add items to cart in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, cart

I have a layout which shows all the available items in a recycler view and bottom bar which shows how many items the users has selected and the total price along with a checkout button.

The problem is how to pass the selected data from the recycler view to the activity.Since,data binding is done by the adapter i cant update the Bottom bar.

Comment: consider that `stock` and `cart` are ordinary not the same thing ...in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

You could add an interface in the adapter that has two methods:

```
 interface ICart {

    void onItemSelected(Item item);

    void onItemRemoved(Item item);

}
```

Then implement that in your activity.

```
public class CartActivity implements ICart {}
```